Above which altitude an airplane is required to have oxygen mask for the passenger?
Is there a maximum altitude above which an aircraft needs to have oxygen mask available for the passengers?

14 CFR 91.211 spells out the supplemental oxygen requirements:

(a) General. No person may operate a civil aircraft of U.S. registry
(3) At cabin pressure altitudes above 15,000 feet (MSL) unless each occupant of the aircraft is provided with supplemental oxygen.

For Pressurized aircraft:

(i) At flight altitudes above flight level 250 unless at least a 10-minute supply of supplemental oxygen, in addition to any oxygen required to satisfy paragraph (a) of this section, is available for each occupant of the aircraft for use in the event that a descent is necessitated by loss of cabin pressurization; and...

Note that it doesn't specify a "mask", (some GA systems use a delivery system to the nostrils) or that the passengers are required to use what is provided or available.

Does this means that a pressurized aircraft certified to fly max altitude FL 24 doesn't need to have the typical passenger supplemental oxygen masks that drops when the aircraft losses pressurization?

Apparently that is correct.

perfect that was my doubt. thanks

@Gabe It's up to FL250. Planes without masks with FL250 ceilings include the Dash 8 (optional masks extend to FL270) and ATR-42/72 (there's only masks for 25% of the passengers, cabin crew manually release them for passengers that need it).
